# Having an issue with "gladLoadGL". I'm getting an error saying it does not take 1 argument

Tags: opengl, glad

I'm trying to do some openGL tutorials (https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick_guide.html#quick_example) and one of the functions is gladLoadGL. The line of code is "gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);" however when I try to run I get the error "C2660 'gladLoadGL': function does not take 1 arguments".

I've tried searching online but no one seems to be having the same issue as I am. I've looked into the glad.h file and the function has a warning "Function definition gladLoadGL not found" which maybe where my issue is coming from. When I generated the glad code (https://glad.dav1d.de/) the settings I had where Language C/C++, Specification OpenGL, gl Version 4.6, Profile Core, and Generate a loader was ticked.

```cpp
gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use:

**a)** a loader from an already know API that has a loader, e.g. [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/)

```
gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);
```

or **b)** directly:

```
gladLoadGL();
```

Notice the different used function.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ended up using your second solution and I also had forgotten to include glad.c .Thank you so much

Comment: first one worked for me while second one didn't