# How to init glad without the glfw loader (using windows headers)

Tags: c++, windows, glfw, hwnd, glad

I'm trying to render to a HWND window using a HGLRC OpenGL rendering context.

I have to initiate the glad but `gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)wglGetProcAddress))` and the `gladLoadGL()` seems to be failing.

> glad OpenGL version : 4.0 core

> I've been using the glfwGetProcAdress function until now.

How can I make the gladLoadGLLoader function work? Would it be that I have to indicate the version of the OpenGL to the wglGetProcAddress function or maybe I should use another loader?

Update 1 :

in the gladLoadGLLoader function the problem is `(PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC)load("glGetString")` returns null

```c
int gladLoadGLLoader(GLADloadproc load) {
    GLVersion.major = 0; GLVersion.minor = 0;
    glGetString = (PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC)load("glGetString");
    
    if(glGetString == NULL) //Returns there (fails)
        return 0;
    
    if(glGetString(GL_VERSION) == NULL) 
        return 0;
    
    find_coreGL();
    load_GL_VERSION_1_0(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_1_1(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_1_2(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_1_3(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_1_4(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_1_5(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_2_0(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_2_1(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_3_0(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_3_1(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_3_2(load);
    load_GL_VERSION_3_3(load);


    if (!find_extensionsGL()) return 0;
    return GLVersion.major != 0 || GLVersion.minor != 0;
}
```

Update 2 :

The problem seems to be that `wglGetProcAddress` is being used to load core OpenGL functions. However, `wglGetProcAddress` can only load specific WGL extensions and not core OpenGL stuff.

Update 3 :

As an additional note to the update 2, it seems that the GLFW library also uses `wglGetProcAddress` for the `glfwGetProcAddress` function

Solved :

```
void *GetAnyGLFuncAddress(const char *name)
{
  void *p = (void *)wglGetProcAddress(name);
  if(p == 0 ||
    (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) ||
    (p == (void*)-1) )
  {
    HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll");
    p = (void *)GetProcAddress(module, name);
  }

  return p;
}

void Renderer::initGlad(){
    //Init GLAD
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)GetAnyGLFuncAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    }    
}
```

Replacing `wglGetProcAddress` with the `void *GetAnyGLFuncAddress(const char *name)` function solves the problem.

Comment: Did you create a WGL context first? May you show your code for further debugging? You should consider reading [Creating an OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_%28WGL%29).

Comment: Yes. First I created an OpenGL context successfuly using wglCreateContextAttribsARB . Then make it current using wglMakeCurrent function. And made the versions of the OpenGL compatible. And also checked every step if there was an error. 
I don't think the issue is related to the OpenGL context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58054254/3871028

Comment: would [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) and specifically the `GetAnyGlFuncAddress`, be interesting to you?

Comment: YEESSS! That was it. I've been dealing with that stuff since the morning. Checked my OpenGL context creation function like 20 times. Thank you very much for your concern. Updating my quesiton rn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*The problem  seems to be that `wglGetProcAddress` is being used to load core OpenGL functions. However, `wglGetProcAddress` can only load specific WGL extensions and not core OpenGL stuff.*" Indeed, `wglGetProcAddress` does have limitations. But it **can load** OpenGL functions - in fact, most all of them. The restriction is on loading extremely old GL functions that date back to OpenGL *1.1*. This is the reason why `glGetString` is null - it's an OpenGL 1.1 function, which isn't supported by it.

Fortunately, these age-old functions are the ones that happen to be directly exported by the Windows libary `opengl32.dll` itself. Therefore, you can use the Windows function `GetProcAddress` on `opengl32.dll` for these functions. However `GetProcAddress`, of course, does not work on newer GL functions.

But we can create a new function to 'bridge the gap' between these two:

```c
void *GetAnyGLFuncAddress(const char *name)
{
  void *p = (void *)wglGetProcAddress(name); // load newer functions via wglGetProcAddress
  if(p == 0 ||
    (p == (void*)0x1) || (p == (void*)0x2) || (p == (void*)0x3) ||
    (p == (void*)-1) ) // does it return NULL - i.e. is the function not found?
  {
    // could be an OpenGL 1.1 function
    HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("opengl32.dll"); 
    p = (void *)GetProcAddress(module, name); // then import directly from GL lib
  }

  return p;
}
```

This function, as you can see, first calls `wglGetProcAddress`, which works for OpenGL 1.1+ functions. Next, it determines if `p` is null, meaning that this function call was not successful. Then it attempts to call `GetProcAddress`, working for GL1.1 functions.

Then, it's simply a matter of calling `gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)GetAnyGLFuncAddress))`.

---

In practice, it is not neccessary to implement such a function yourself. GLAD has the inbuilt function, `gladLoadGL`, which if you look at the code, calls `gladLoadGLLoader` for the internal `get_proc` function. The code in this function does exactly what we've implemented (removing the `#if`/`#endif`s for other OSes):

```c
void* get_proc(const char *namez) {
    void* result = NULL;
    if(libGL == NULL) return NULL;
    if(gladGetProcAddressPtr != NULL) {
        result = gladGetProcAddressPtr(namez); // essentially wglGetProcAddress - see glad's internal open_gl()
    }
    if(result == NULL) {
        result = (void*)GetProcAddress((HMODULE) libGL, namez);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It tries to load the OpenGL function via `wglGetProcAddress`, and then if that fails, uses  `GetProcAddress`. Therefore, you can just call `gladLoadGL`.

---

<sup>The wiki page [Load OpenGL Functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) has a lot of info on this.</sup>